# Split a sentence ignoring characters in Java

Tags: java, string, loops, split

I Want to write a program that reads one line of input text and **breaks** it up into words.

The (solution)
words should be output one per line. A word is defined to be a sequence of letters.

**Any characters in the input that are not letters should be discarded.**

**For example, if the user inputs the line:**

```
He said, "That’s not a good idea."
```

**then the output of the program should be:**

```
He
said
That
‘s
not
a
good
idea
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in); // user input
        String line = stdIn.nextLine(); // read line
        String[] words = line.split("[^a-zA-Z]+"); // split by all non-alphabetic characters (a regex)
        for (String word : words) { // iterate through the words
            System.out.println(word); // print word with a newline
        }
    }
}
```

It won't include the apostrophe in the token `'s`, but I don't know why you included that. It's not a letter, after all, and I read your first bold sentence. I hope the comments help explain how it works. There will be a trailing empty line, but that should be easy for you to fix if you really need to.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a regex

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w'’]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("He said, \"That’s not a good idea.\"");
    while (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
```